# Association rules mining

Tags: association-rules

Consider for a dataset with many transactions each with items sold. Now, consider that we are given minimum support level and confidence level and that we have constructed the tables L1 and L2 each having many item sets that are all higher than the minimum support level. Consider that we can further have many three combinations items sets, however, none of them is higher than the minimum support level, therefore L3 is empty, then can we generate association rules from L2 ? or we just cant generate any rules since L3 is empty?